# Polymorphic association using namespaced classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class, polymorphism

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to set a polymorphic association using namespaced classes.

**Migrations** are:

```
create_table :users_users do |t|
  t.integer :id
  t.string :full_name
  t.references :userable, :polymorphic => true
end

create_table :users_profiles do |t|
  t.integer :id
  ...
end

create_table :users_accounts do |t|
  t.integer :id
  ...
end
```

**Classes** are:

```
class Users::User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Association ...
end

class Users::Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Association ...
end

class Users::Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Association ...
end
```

**How I must write code associations for above classes** (using `:class_name => "Users:User", ...`?) **in order to *auto-create* and *auto-destroy* associated model records, "mapping" those in the `users_users` table and viceversa?**

*Do you have some advice about that? What string values I will have in `userable_type` attributes (example: 'Users::Profile', 'Profile', ...)?*

Comment: It's unclear exactly how you're wanting these relationships to work. Using polymorphism they way you've described it with your migration, a Users::User would be able to belong to a Users::Profile or a Users::Account, but not both at the same time. Is that what you were wanting, or were you thinking a User can have one profile and can belong to an account? If that is the case, polymorphism isn't what you're needing to use - a profile could just belong to a user and accounts could have many users through a join table.

Comment: @idlefingers - A User can have one Profile OR one Account, not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To setup the associations, you don't need to use class name...

```
class Users::User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :userable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Users::Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, :as => :userable, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Users::Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, :as => :userable, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

`:dependent => :destroy` will deal with deleting them when the Users::User is destroyed, but in terms of creating, you've got the same options as you have with normal relationships. If you're doing it from a form, it's best to use nested attributes.

In the database, the userable_type column would include the namespace. So it'd be 'Users::Account' or 'Users::Profile'.

Comment: Is there a way to use plain Account or Profile in the database (without the namespace)?